# Code works with two products but when I add a third product code grabs data but doesn't save it only for third product. What's wrong with it?

Tags: excel, vba

The code still works for oil and gas. It will find and pull in the refined data, I can see it on the current prices worksheet while it's running but when it's finished running it will delete the refined data and doesn't populate any of the other sheets for refined only. I copied all code bits for oil and replaced the word oil with refined.

```
    Sub Prices()
        Dim asOfDate As Date
        Dim i, c, r As Integer
        Dim break As Integer
        Dim wf As WorksheetFunction

        ws_currentprices.Activate
        'Copy date from summary ws to pop asofdate
        Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, BUCKET_COL) = ws_summary.Cells(1, 6)
        If IsEmpty(Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, BUCKET_COL)) Then
            asOfDate = Date
        Else
            asOfDate = Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, BUCKET_COL)
        End If

        'Setting to manual calculation must happen after asofdate has been populated
        Application.Calculation = xlManual

        'Clear all data and headers from the current prices ws
        Range(Cells(STATUS_ROW, FIRSTDATA_COL), Cells(110, 50)).ClearContents

        Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

        'Build arraylist of gas markets
        Dim gasArray As Object
        Set gasArray = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        i = 1
        Do Until (IsEmpty(ws_gasmarkets.Cells(i, 4)))
            If StrComp(ws_gasmarkets.Cells(i, 4), "Yes", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then gasArray.Add ws_gasmarkets.Cells(i, 2).Value
            i = i + 1
        Loop

        'Process arraylist of gas markets
        c = FIRSTDATA_COL
        For i = 0 To gasArray.Count - 1
            Days = 0
            Do Until Month(wf.WorkDay(asOfDate, Days)) <> Month(asOfDate)

                Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, c) = gasArray(i)
                Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, c) = CDate(wf.WorkDay(asOfDate, Days))
                Cells(DATASOURCE_ROW, c) = "Official"
                Cells(MARKETTYPE_ROW, c) = "Gas"

                break = c - 1

                c = c + 1
                Days = Days - 1

            Loop

            Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, c) = gasArray(i)
            Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, c) = dhLastDayInMonth(DateSerial(Year(asOfDate), Month(asOfDate) - 1, 1))
            Cells(DATASOURCE_ROW, c) = "Official"
            Cells(MARKETTYPE_ROW, c) = "Gas"

            break = c - 1

            c = c + 1
        Next

        'Build arraylist of oil markets
        Dim oilArray As Object
        Set oilArray = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        i = 1
        Do Until (IsEmpty(ws_oilmarkets.Cells(i, 4)))
            If StrComp(ws_oilmarkets.Cells(i, 4), "Yes", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then oilArray.Add ws_oilmarkets.Cells(i, 2).Value
            i = i + 1
        Loop

        'Process arraylist of oil markets
        For i = 0 To oilArray.Count - 1
            Days = 0
            Do Until Month(wf.WorkDay(asOfDate, Days)) <> Month(asOfDate)

                Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, c) = oilArray(i)
                Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, c) = CDate(wf.WorkDay(asOfDate, Days))
                Cells(DATASOURCE_ROW, c) = "Official"
                Cells(MARKETTYPE_ROW, c) = "Oil"

                break = c - 1

                c = c + 1
                Days = Days - 1

            Loop

            Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, c) = oilArray(i)
            Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, c) = dhLastDayInMonth(DateSerial(Year(asOfDate), Month(asOfDate) - 1, 1))
            Cells(DATASOURCE_ROW, c) = "Official"
            Cells(MARKETTYPE_ROW, c) = "Oil"

            break = c - 1

            c = c + 1
        Next

        'Build arraylist of REFINED markets
        Dim REFINEDArray As Object
        Set REFINEDArray = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        i = 1
        Do Until (IsEmpty(ws_REFINEDmarkets.Cells(i, 4)))
            If StrComp(ws_REFINEDmarkets.Cells(i, 4), "Yes", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then REFINEDArray.Add ws_REFINEDmarkets.Cells(i, 2).Value
            i = i + 1
        Loop

        'Process arraylist of REFINED markets
        For i = 0 To REFINEDArray.Count - 1
            Days = 0
            Do Until Month(wf.WorkDay(asOfDate, Days)) <> Month(asOfDate)

                Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, c) = REFINEDArray(i)
                Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, c) = CDate(wf.WorkDay(asOfDate, Days))
                Cells(DATASOURCE_ROW, c) = "Official"
                Cells(MARKETTYPE_ROW, c) = "REFINED"

                break = c - 1

                c = c + 1
                Days = Days - 1

            Loop

            Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, c) = REFINEDArray(i)
            Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, c) = dhLastDayInMonth(DateSerial(Year(asOfDate), Month(asOfDate) - 1, 1))
            Cells(DATASOURCE_ROW, c) = "Official"
            Cells(MARKETTYPE_ROW, c) = "Refined"

            break = c - 1

            c = c + 1
        Next

        'Downloads current prices from Kiodex
        DownloadCurrentPrices

        'Remove invalid pricing columns
        If (PricesCleanup) Then

            'Setup GAS and OIL worksheets
            REFINEDSetup
            GasSetup
            OilSetup

            'Calculate GAS and OIL worksheets
            ws_REFINED.Calculate
            ws_oil.Calculate
            ws_gas.Calculate

            'Refresh and display summary worksheet
            'ws_summary.Calculate
            Calculate
            ws_summary.Activate

            Refresh

            'Set data source value based on NYMEX - Not Updated (0), Preliminary (1), or Updated (2)
            c = FIRSTDATA_COL
            ds = 0
            gaschk = False
            oilchk = False
            REFINEDchk = False
            Do Until (IsEmpty(ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, c)) Or (gaschk And oilchk And REFINEDchk))
                If (StrComp(ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, c), "GD Henry Hub", vbTextCompare) And Not gaschk) Then
                    If (ws_currentprices.Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, c) = ws_currentprices.Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, BUCKET_COL)) Then
                        'Data for current date
                        If (StrComp(ws_currentprices.Cells(DATASOURCE_ROW, c), "Official", vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
                            'Data is official
                            ds = ds + 2
                        Else
                            'Data is global
                            ds = ds + 1
                        End If
                    Else
                        'Data for prior date
                        ds = ds + 0
                    End If
                    gaschk = True
                End If
                If (StrComp(ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, c), "NYMEX WTI", vbTextCompare) And Not oilchk) Then
                    If (ws_currentprices.Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, c) = ws_currentprices.Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, BUCKET_COL)) Then
                        'Data for current date
                        If (StrComp(ws_currentprices.Cells(DATASOURCE_ROW, c), "Official", vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
                            'Data is official
                            ds = ds + 2
                        Else
                            'Data is global
                            ds = ds + 1
                        End If
                    Else
                        'Data for prior date
                        ds = ds + 0
                    End If
                    oilchk = True
                End If
            '***REFINED addition***
        If (StrComp(ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, c), "OPIS Ethane Mt Belv non TET", vbTextCompare) And Not REFINEDchk) Then
                    If (ws_currentprices.Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, c) = ws_currentprices.Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, BUCKET_COL)) Then
                        'Data for current date
                        If (StrComp(ws_currentprices.Cells(DATASOURCE_ROW, c), "Official", vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
                            'Data is official
                            ds = ds + 2
                        Else
                            'Data is global
                            ds = ds + 1
                        End If
                    Else
                        'Data for prior date
                        ds = ds + 0
                    End If
                    REFINEDchk = True
                End If
                c = c + 1
            Loop

            Select Case ds
                Case Is >= 4
                    ws_summary.Range("SummaryDataSource") = "Updated"
                Case Is > 0
                    ws_summary.Range("SummaryDataSource") = "Preliminary"
                Case Else
                    ws_summary.Range("SummaryDataSource") = "Not Updated"
            End Select
        Else
            ws_summary.Activate
            ws_summary.Range("SummaryDataSource") = "Not Updated"
        End If

        'Set last updated date
        ws_summary.Range("LastUpdatedDateTime") = Now

        Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
        Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1

        'Update BOKF Pricing History
        If Format(asOfDate, "m/d/yyyy") = Format(WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(asOfDate, 0) + 1, -1), "m/d/yyyy") Then
            Call UpdateBOKFPriceHistory(Format(DateSerial(Year(asOfDate), Month(asOfDate) + 1, 1), "mm/dd/yyyy"), False)
        End If

    End Sub

    'This function checks the Current Prices tab for any columns that are duplicates of the day before or weekends and deletes the column
    Function PricesCleanup() As Boolean

        Dim r, c As Integer
        Dim removeCount As Integer
        Dim removeColumn As Boolean
        Dim isGas, isOil, isREFINED As Boolean

        c = FIRSTDATA_COL
        removeCount = 0

        Do Until IsEmpty(ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, c)) 'check every col of prices
            'Start at the row of the first date and reset remove flag
            r = FIRSTDATE_ROW
            removeColumn = True

            'Check each column, at least until there is a discrepancy between prices so we know it's not a holiday
            Do Until ((r > 12 And IsEmpty(ws_currentprices.Cells(r, c))) Or r > 60 Or Not removeColumn)
                'If the prices don't match, we know it's not a holiday
                If (ws_currentprices.Cells(r, c) <> ws_currentprices.Cells(r, c + 1)) Then
                    'If the first row is empty or matches second row, it's likely due to near EoM index shifting and requires special handling
                    If r = FIRSTDATE_ROW Then
                        If IsEmpty(ws_currentprices.Cells(r, c)) Then
                            'Oil index swap
                            removeColumn = False
                        End If
                        If (ws_currentprices.Cells(r, c) = ws_currentprices.Cells(r + 1, c) And ws_currentprices.Cells(MARKETTYPE_ROW, c) = "Gas") Then
                            removeColumn = False
                        End If

                            '***Refined
                        If (ws_currentprices.Cells(r, c) = ws_currentprices.Cells(r + 1, c) And ws_currentprices.Cells(MARKETTYPE_ROW, c) = "REFINED") Then
                            removeColumn = False
                        End If
                    Else
                        'Not index related and no match, so don't remove column
                        removeColumn = False
                    End If
                End If
                r = r + 1
            Loop

            'Check for weekend dates or dates from prior month
            If Weekday(ws_currentprices.Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, c)) = 1 Or Weekday(ws_currentprices.Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, c)) = 7 Or Month(ws_currentprices.Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, c)) <> Month(ws_currentprices.Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, BUCKET_COL)) Then
                removeColumn = True
            End If

            'Remove column if flagged
            If removeColumn Then
                removeCount = removeCount + 1
                ws_currentprices.Columns(c).EntireColumn.Delete
                c = c - 1
            End If

            'Copy up spot price
            If Not IsEmpty(ws_currentprices.Cells(FIRSTDATE_ROW, c)) Then
                ws_currentprices.Cells(SPOT_ROW, c) = ws_currentprices.Cells(FIRSTDATE_ROW, c)
            ElseIf Not IsEmpty(ws_currentprices.Cells(FIRSTDATE_ROW + 1, c)) Then
                ws_currentprices.Cells(SPOT_ROW, c) = ws_currentprices.Cells(FIRSTDATE_ROW + 1, c)
            Else
                ws_currentprices.Cells(SPOT_ROW, c) = ""
            End If


            c = c + 1
        Loop

        'Check if any columns are left and return bool value
        isGas = False
        isOil = False
        isREFINED = False
        c = FIRSTDATA_COL
        Do Until IsEmpty(ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, c))
            If (ws_currentprices.Cells(MARKETTYPE_ROW, c) = "Gas") Then
                isGas = True
            ElseIf (ws_currentprices.Cells(MARKETTYPE_ROW, c) = "Oil") Then
                isOil = True
            ElseIf (ws_currentprices.Cells(MARKETTYPE_ROW, c) = "Refined") Then
                isREFINED = True
            End If

            c = c + 1
        Loop

        If (isGas And isOil And isREFINED) Then
            PricesCleanup = True
        Else
            PricesCleanup = False
        End If

    End Function

    Sub GasSetup()
        Dim cpr, cpc, r, c, marketcount, marketstartrow As Integer
        Dim index As Double
        Const YEARMONTH_COL = 1
        Const DATE_COL = 2
        Const SPOT_COL = 3
        Const markettype = "GAS"

        ws_gas.UsedRange.ClearContents

        cpc = FIRSTDATA_COL
        marketcount = 0

        'Loop through each column in currentprices looking for gas markets
        Do Until (IsEmpty(ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, cpc)))
            If StrComp(ws_currentprices.Cells(MARKETTYPE_ROW, cpc), markettype, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                'This is a gas column
                cpr = FIRSTDATE_ROW
                c = 1
                If StrComp(ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, cpc), ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, cpc - 1), vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                    'Sort prior market data by date
                    If marketcount <> 0 Then
                        ws_gas.Range("A" & marketstartrow + 1 & ":FF" & r).Sort Key1:=ws_gas.Range("B" & marketstartrow + 1 & ":FF" & r), _
                        order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
                    End If

                    'Start each new market on row divisible by 30 + 1 to prevent any issues with summary table
                    marketstartrow = marketcount * 30 + 1
                    marketcount = marketcount + 1

                    r = marketstartrow
                    'Add labels for new market
                    ws_gas.Cells(r, YEARMONTH_COL) = ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, cpc)
                    ws_gas.Cells(r + 1, YEARMONTH_COL) = "YEARMONTH"
                    ws_gas.Cells(r + 1, DATE_COL) = "Date"
                    ws_gas.Cells(r + 1, SPOT_COL) = "Spot"

                    c = c + 3
                    For i = 0 To 59
                        ws_gas.Cells(r + 1, c + i) = i + 1
                    Next
                    r = r + 2
                End If

                'Populate date
                ws_gas.Cells(r, DATE_COL) = ws_currentprices.Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, cpc)
                ws_gas.Cells(r, YEARMONTH_COL) = Year(ws_gas.Cells(r, DATE_COL)) & "." & Month(ws_gas.Cells(r, DATE_COL))

                'Populate spot
                ws_gas.Cells(r, SPOT_COL) = ws_currentprices.Cells(SPOT_ROW, cpc)
                c = 4

                'Populate row
                Do Until cpr > 60 And IsEmpty(ws_currentprices.Cells(cpr, cpc))
                    ws_gas.Cells(r, c) = ws_currentprices.Cells(cpr, cpc)
                    cpr = cpr + 1
                    c = c + 1
                Loop

                r = r + 1
            End If

            cpc = cpc + 1
        Loop

        'Sort final market data by date
        ws_gas.Range("A" & marketstartrow + 1 & ":FF" & r).Sort Key1:=ws_gas.Range("B" & marketstartrow + 1 & ":B" & r), _
        order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

        'Iterate through the Nymex data to update market index values
        r = 2
        index = 0
        Do Until (IsEmpty(ws_gas.Cells(r, DATE_COL)))
            If IsEmpty(ws_gas.Cells(r, DATE_COL + 2)) Then
                'No value for current month, so take prior row value for index
               Call UpdateIndexes(markettype, ws_gas.Cells(r - 1, DATE_COL), ws_gas.Cells(r - 1, DATE_COL + 2))

               Exit Do
            End If
            r = r + 1
        Loop

    End Sub

    Sub OilSetup()
        Dim cpr, cpc, r, c, marketcount, marketstartrow As Integer
        Dim index As Double
        Const YEARMONTH_COL = 1
        Const DATE_COL = 2
        Const SPOT_COL = 3
        Const markettype = "OIL"

        ws_oil.UsedRange.ClearContents

        cpc = FIRSTDATA_COL
        marketcount = 0
        marketstartrow = 0

        'Loop through each column in currentprices looking for gas markets
        Do Until (IsEmpty(ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, cpc)))
            If StrComp(ws_currentprices.Cells(MARKETTYPE_ROW, cpc), markettype, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                'This is a gas column
                cpr = FIRSTDATE_ROW
                c = 1
                If StrComp(ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, cpc), ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, cpc - 1), vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                    'Sort prior market data by date
                    If marketcount <> 0 Then
                        ws_oil.Range("A" & marketstartrow + 1 & ":FF" & r).Sort Key1:=ws_oil.Range("B" & marketstartrow + 1 & ":FF" & r), _
                        order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
                    End If

                    'Start each new market on row divisible by 30 + 1 to prevent any issues with summary table
                    marketstartrow = marketcount * 30 + 1
                    marketcount = marketcount + 1

                    r = marketstartrow

                    'Add labels for new market
                    ws_oil.Cells(r, YEARMONTH_COL) = ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, cpc)
                    ws_oil.Cells(r + 1, YEARMONTH_COL) = "YEARMONTH"
                    ws_oil.Cells(r + 1, DATE_COL) = "Date"
                    ws_oil.Cells(r + 1, SPOT_COL) = "Spot"

                    c = c + 3
                    For i = 0 To 59
                        ws_oil.Cells(r + 1, c + i) = i + 1
                    Next
                    r = r + 2
                End If

                'Populate date
                ws_oil.Cells(r, DATE_COL) = ws_currentprices.Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, cpc)
                ws_oil.Cells(r, YEARMONTH_COL) = Year(ws_oil.Cells(r, DATE_COL)) & "." & Month(ws_oil.Cells(r, DATE_COL))

                'Populate spot
                ws_oil.Cells(r, SPOT_COL) = ws_currentprices.Cells(SPOT_ROW, cpc)
                c = 4

                'Populate row
                Do Until cpr > 60 And IsEmpty(ws_currentprices.Cells(cpr, cpc))
                    ws_oil.Cells(r, c) = ws_currentprices.Cells(cpr, cpc)
                    cpr = cpr + 1
                    c = c + 1
                Loop

                r = r + 1
            End If

            cpc = cpc + 1
        Loop

        'Sort final market data by date
        ws_oil.Range("A" & marketstartrow + 1 & ":FF" & r).Sort Key1:=ws_oil.Range("B" & marketstartrow + 1 & ":B" & r), _
        order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

        'Iterate through the Nymex data to update market index values
        r = 2
        index = 0
        Do Until (IsEmpty(ws_oil.Cells(r, DATE_COL)))
            If IsEmpty(ws_oil.Cells(r, DATE_COL + 2)) Then
                'No value for current month, so take prior row value for index
               Call UpdateIndexes(markettype, ws_oil.Cells(r - 1, DATE_COL), ws_oil.Cells(r - 1, DATE_COL + 2))

               Exit Do
            End If
            r = r + 1
        Loop

    End Sub

    Sub REFINEDSetup()
        Dim cpr, cpc, r, c, marketcount, marketstartrow As Integer
        Dim index As Double
        Const YEARMONTH_COL = 1
        Const DATE_COL = 2
        Const SPOT_COL = 3
        Const markettype = "REFINED"

        ws_REFINED.UsedRange.ClearContents

        cpc = FIRSTDATA_COL
        marketcount = 0
        marketstartrow = 0

        'Loop through each column in currentprices looking for REFINED markets
        Do Until (IsEmpty(ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, cpc)))
            If StrComp(ws_currentprices.Cells(MARKETTYPE_ROW, cpc), markettype, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                'This is a REFINED column
                cpr = FIRSTDATE_ROW
                c = 1
                If StrComp(ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, cpc), ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, cpc - 1), vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                    'Sort prior market data by date
                    If marketcount <> 0 Then
                        ws_REFINED.Range("A" & marketstartrow + 1 & ":FF" & r).Sort Key1:=ws_REFINED.Range("B" & marketstartrow + 1 & ":FF" & r), _
                        order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
                    End If

                    'Start each new market on row divisible by 30 + 1 to prevent any issues with summary table
                    marketstartrow = marketcount * 30 + 1
                    marketcount = marketcount + 1

                    r = marketstartrow

                    'Add labels for new market
                    ws_REFINED.Cells(r, YEARMONTH_COL) = ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, cpc)
                    ws_REFINED.Cells(r + 1, YEARMONTH_COL) = "YEARMONTH"
                    ws_REFINED.Cells(r + 1, DATE_COL) = "Date"
                    ws_REFINED.Cells(r + 1, SPOT_COL) = "Spot"

                    c = c + 3
                    For i = 0 To 59
                        ws_REFINED.Cells(r + 1, c + i) = i + 1
                    Next
                    r = r + 2
                End If

                'Populate date
                ws_REFINED.Cells(r, DATE_COL) = ws_currentprices.Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, cpc)
                ws_REFINED.Cells(r, YEARMONTH_COL) = Year(ws_REFINED.Cells(r, DATE_COL)) & "." & Month(ws_REFINED.Cells(r, DATE_COL))

                'Populate spot
                ws_REFINED.Cells(r, SPOT_COL) = ws_currentprices.Cells(SPOT_ROW, cpc)
                c = 4

                'Populate row
                Do Until cpr > 60 And IsEmpty(ws_currentprices.Cells(cpr, cpc))
                    ws_REFINED.Cells(r, c) = ws_currentprices.Cells(cpr, cpc)
                    cpr = cpr + 1
                    c = c + 1
                Loop

                r = r + 1
            End If

            cpc = cpc + 1
        Loop

        'Sort final market data by date
        ws_REFINED.Range("A" & marketstartrow + 1 & ":FF" & r).Sort Key1:=ws_REFINED.Range("B" & marketstartrow + 1 & ":B" & r), _
        order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

        'Iterate through the Nymex data to update market index values
        r = 2
        index = 0
        Do Until (IsEmpty(ws_REFINED.Cells(r, DATE_COL)))
            If IsEmpty(ws_REFINED.Cells(r, DATE_COL + 2)) Then
                'No value for current month, so take prior row value for index
               Call UpdateIndexes(markettype, ws_REFINED.Cells(r - 1, DATE_COL), ws_REFINED.Cells(r - 1, DATE_COL + 2))

               Exit Do
            End If
            r = r + 1
        Loop

    End Sub
```

Comment: Too much code here....

Comment: I inherited this code and I don't really know programming so I've been winging it. I wasn't sure if any of the extra code is relevant to find the solution to the problem so I included it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[StrComp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/strcomp-function) in VBA does not return True or False. It returns -1, 0, or 1 depending on the results of the string comparison. If the two strings match for the particular type of comparison chosen then `StrComp` will return 0.

However, VBA treats 0 as being equivalent to False - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/boolean-data-type). This means that if you write a `StrComp` where the two strings match, but you forget to compare the results to zero, then you will get a result of False if you use the result as if it were a Boolean (e.g. in an If statement).

In your code, you have:

```
If (StrComp(ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, c), "GD Henry Hub", vbTextCompare) And Not gaschk) Then

If (StrComp(ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, c), "NYMEX WTI", vbTextCompare) And Not oilchk) Then

If (StrComp(ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, c), "OPIS Ethane Mt Belv non TET", vbTextCompare) And Not REFINEDchk) Then
```

All three statements are incorrectly using the result of `StrComp` as if it were a Boolean. Change all three to `StrComp(...) = 0` instead