# Function deletes lines it shouldn't

Tags: excel, vba

When I execute this it will delete the "Refined" lines and when I comment this function out it the "Refined" lines don't get deleted. I inherited this code and I have added every section to has "Refined" because I'm attempting to add extra products besides "gas" and "oil" but I really don't know VBA or programming. I've just been winging it and it's mostly worked except this section.

My question is what's wrong with what I added to the code? I edited or added every line that has the word "refined" in it. It works as intended for oil and gas but will always delete the refined column. When it executes data for oil, gas, and refined populates the worksheet but it will instantly delete all the refined columns that it pulled in.

I don't have the proficient to rewrite it as a different do until loop without some sort of code template.

```
This function checks the Current Prices tab for any columns that are duplicates of the day before or weekends and deletes the column
Function PricesCleanup() As Boolean

    Dim r, c As Integer
    Dim removeCount As Integer
    Dim removeColumn As Boolean
    Dim isGas, isOil, isRefined As Boolean

    c = FIRSTDATA_COL
    removeCount = 0

    Do Until IsEmpty(ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, c)) 'check every col of prices
        'Start at the row of the first date and reset remove flag
        r = FIRSTDATE_ROW
        removeColumn = True

        'Check each column, at least until there is a discrepancy between prices so we know it's not a holiday
        Do Until ((r > 12 And IsEmpty(ws_currentprices.Cells(r, c))) Or r > 60 Or Not removeColumn)
            'If the prices don't match, we know it's not a holiday
            If (ws_currentprices.Cells(r, c) <> ws_currentprices.Cells(r, c + 1)) Then
                'If the first row is empty or matches second row, it's likely due to near EoM index shifting and requires special handling
                If r = FIRSTDATE_ROW Then
                    If IsEmpty(ws_currentprices.Cells(r, c)) Then
                        'Oil index swap
                        removeColumn = False
                    End If
                    If (ws_currentprices.Cells(r, c) = ws_currentprices.Cells(r + 1, c) And ws_currentprices.Cells(MARKETTYPE_ROW, c) = "Gas") Then
                        'Gas index swap so clear cell and allow to continue but only if within the last few workdays of the month
                        If (DateDiff("d", WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(ws_currentprices.Cells(r, BUCKET_COL), -1), ws_currentprices.Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, c)) > -3) Then
                            ws_currentprices.Cells(r, c).ClearContents
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    'Not index related and no match, so don't remove column
                    removeColumn = False
                End If
            End If
            r = r + 1
        Loop

        'Check for weekend dates or dates from prior month
        If Weekday(ws_currentprices.Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, c)) = 1 Or Weekday(ws_currentprices.Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, c)) = 7 Or Month(ws_currentprices.Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, c)) <> Month(ws_currentprices.Cells(ASOFDATE_ROW, BUCKET_COL)) Then
            removeColumn = True
        End If

        'Remove column if flagged
        If removeColumn Then
            removeCount = removeCount + 1
            ws_currentprices.Columns(c).EntireColumn.Delete
            c = c - 1
        End If

        'Copy up spot price
        If Not IsEmpty(ws_currentprices.Cells(FIRSTDATE_ROW, c)) Then
            ws_currentprices.Cells(SPOT_ROW, c) = ws_currentprices.Cells(FIRSTDATE_ROW, c)
        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(ws_currentprices.Cells(FIRSTDATE_ROW + 1, c)) Then
            ws_currentprices.Cells(SPOT_ROW, c) = ws_currentprices.Cells(FIRSTDATE_ROW + 1, c)
        Else
            ws_currentprices.Cells(SPOT_ROW, c) = ""
        End If


        c = c + 1
    Loop

    'Check if any columns are left and return bool value
    isGas = False
    isOil = False
    isRefined = False
    c = FIRSTDATA_COL
    Do Until IsEmpty(ws_currentprices.Cells(COMMODITY_ROW, c))
        If (ws_currentprices.Cells(MARKETTYPE_ROW, c) = "Gas") Then
            isGas = True
        ElseIf (ws_currentprices.Cells(MARKETTYPE_ROW, c) = "Oil") Then
            isOil = True
        ElseIf (ws_currentprices.Cells(MARKETTYPE_ROW, c) = "Refined") Then
            isRefined = True
        End If

        c = c + 1
    Loop

    If (isGas And isOil And isRefined) Then
        PricesCleanup = True
    Else
        PricesCleanup = False
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Honestly... I would scratch the entire thing and rewrite... `Do Until....Loop` - would use a different construct entirely.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add some commentary on what you are trying to accomplish in lamens terms?

Comment: I have attempted to edit my post to add clarification.

Comment: In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60030055/2127508), some of the cells were getting the value "REFINED" and some were getting the value "Refined". The code in this question will only pick up the cells with the value "Refined" and will ignore the ones which say "REFINED". Not sure how much of an effect this will have though